# Type-safe predicate functions in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, predicate

My goal is to write predicate functions (`isNull` and `isUndefined` for example) in TypeScript which fulfill the following conditions:

1. Can be used standalone: `array.filter(isNull)`
2. Can be logically combined: `array.filter(and(not(isNull), not(isUndefined)))`
3. Uses Type-guards so TypeScript knows for example that the return type of `array.filter(isNull)` will be `null[]`
4. Combined predicates can be extracted into new predicate functions without breaking type inference: `const isNotNull = not(isNull)`

The first two conditions are easy to fulfill:

```js
type Predicate = (i: any) => boolean;

const and = (p1: Predicate, p2: Predicate) =>
    (i: any) => p1(i) && p2(i);

const or = (p1: Predicate, p2: Predicate) =>
    (i: any) => p1(i) || p2(i);

const not = (p: Predicate) =>
    (i: any) => !p(i);

const isNull = (i: any) =>
    i === null;

const isUndefined = (i: any) =>
    i === undefined;

const items = [ "foo", null, 123, undefined, true ];
const filtered = items.filter(and(not(isNull), not(isUndefined)));
console.log(filtered);
```

But because no type-guards are used here TypeScript assumes that the variable `filtered` has the same type as `items` which is `(string,number,boolean,null,undefined)[]` while it actually now should be `(string,number,boolean)[]`.

So I added some typescript magic:

```js
type Diff<T, U> = T extends U ? never : T;

type Predicate<I, O extends I> = (i: I) => i is O;

const and = <I, O1 extends I, O2 extends I>(p1: Predicate<I, O1>, p2: Predicate<I, O2>) =>
    (i: I): i is (O1 & O2) => p1(i) && p2(i);

const or = <I, O1 extends I, O2 extends I>(p1: Predicate<I, O1>, p2: Predicate<I, O2>) =>
    (i: I): i is (O1 | O2) => p1(i) || p2(i);

const not = <I, O extends I>(p: Predicate<I, O>) =>
    (i: I): i is (Diff<I, O>) => !p(i);

const isNull = <I>(i: I | null): i is null =>
    i === null;

const isUndefined = <I>(i: I | undefined): i is undefined =>
    i === undefined;
```

Now it seems to work, `filtered` is correctly reduced to type `(string,number,boolean)[]`.

But because `not(isNull)` might be used quite often I want to extract this into a new predicate function:

```js
const isNotNull = not(isNull);
```

While this perfectly works at runtime unfortunately it doesn't compile (TypeScript 3.3.3 with strict mode enabled):

```
Argument of type '<I>(i: I | null) => i is null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Predicate<{}, {}>'.
  Type predicate 'i is null' is not assignable to 'i is {}'.
    Type 'null' is not assignable to type '{}'.ts(2345)
```

So I guess while using the predicates as argument for the arrays `filter` method TypeScript can infer the type of `I` from the array but when extracting the predicate into a separate function then this no longer works and TypeScript falls back to the base object type `{}` which breaks everything.

Is there a way to fix this? Some trick to convince TypeScript to stick to the generic type `I` instead of resolving it to `{}` when defining the `isNotNull` function? Or is this a limitation of TypeScript and can't be done currently?

Comment: This is cool idea! What TS version do you use? Your code works well in TS Playground https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/ right now.

`let a2 = [1, 2, 'sdfsf', null].filter(isNotNull); // let a2: (string | number)[]`

Comment: I'm using latest Typescript 3.3.3 in strict mode. Enable at least the `strictNullChecks` option in TS Playground to reproduce the problem. It won't compile and hovering over `a2` in your example will show wrong type `never[]`.

Comment: TS has a weakness in that you can't mix User-Defined Type Guards with standard return types. I'm not sure what you want to do is possible, and you'll need to define `isNotNull` from scratch rather than compose it.
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards

Comment: @kayahr, i think, it's compiler bug, because in non-strict mode compiler detect types as expected

Comment: Will this work(typescript predicate type) for you
```typescript
// not(null)
 function isNotNull<T>(input: T): input is NonNullable<T> {
  return input != null;
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just found my own two year old question here and tried it again with latest TypeScript version (4.3.5) and the problem does no longer exist. The following code compiles fine and the types are correctly inferred:

```js
type Diff<T, U> = T extends U ? never : T;

type Predicate<I, O extends I> = (i: I) => i is O;

const and = <I, O1 extends I, O2 extends I>(p1: Predicate<I, O1>, p2: Predicate<I, O2>) =>
    (i: I): i is (O1 & O2) => p1(i) && p2(i);

const or = <I, O1 extends I, O2 extends I>(p1: Predicate<I, O1>, p2: Predicate<I, O2>) =>
    (i: I): i is (O1 | O2) => p1(i) || p2(i);

const not = <I, O extends I>(p: Predicate<I, O>) =>
    (i: I): i is (Diff<I, O>) => !p(i);

const isNull = <I>(i: I | null): i is null =>
    i === null;

const isUndefined = <I>(i: I | undefined): i is undefined =>
    i === undefined;

const isNotNull = not(isNull);
const isNotUndefined = not(isUndefined);

const items = [ "foo", null, 123, undefined, true ];
const filtered = items.filter(and(isNotNull, isNotUndefined));
console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: Have to add a comma so it isn't recognized as JSX. Change `isNull = <I>` and `isUndefined = <I>` to `isNull = <I,>` and `isUndefined = <I,>`

Answer (score -1):

Pass type information from context. This code is compiled well

```
// c: (string | number)[]
let c = [1, 2, 'b', 'a', null].filter(not<number | string | null, null>(isNull));
```

Comment: This defeats the whole purpose of the code. I want the compiler to infer the correct type automatically. Manually casting the result to specific types is error-prone.