# Type narrowing with `not` utility function instead of `!` operator

Tags: typescript

I have a function that checks if input is valid string or not.

```js
export function isString(v: unknown): v is string {
   return typeof v === "string";
}

export function not(v) {
   return v === false;
}
```

If want to return early if input is invalid. therefore,

```js
function main(input?: string) {
  if(not(isString(input))) {
     return
  }

  // ERR: the problem occurs here. If fails to recognize `input` as string
  processString(input);
}

function processString(input: string) {
   ...
}
```

As you can see above in comment using `not` helper function if fails to recognize `input`'s type. However, if I switch to `!` operator instead of `not` function, everything works as expected. Can I set up `not` function in any way to use it same way `!` operator? I prefer more verbose syntax if I can help in this case.

Comment: Have you read e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/54801835/3001761?

Comment: No, control flow analysis cannot be arbitrary abstracted over like this.  In order for `not(isString(input))` to have any affect whatsoever like that, we'd need `not()` to be able to act on *type predicates*, and those are not first-class types in the language, really. I could imagine something like `not(isString)(input)` working, but not `not(isString(input))`.  Does that fully address the question? Or am I missing something?